# Android menu disappears on locale, what did I do wrong?

Tags: android, locale

I have a working app, which I want to translate into another languages.

I made multiple folders in my res folder:

```
values-en
```

and

```
values-hu
```

for example. But if I use other than the default

```
values
```

folder, the menu(ActionBar) of the app disappears. Everything is fine if I use the default values folder.

Can provide additional structure/code, if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by if I use other than the default values folder? Do you mean when you change the locale of the phone and restart your app?

Comment: Yes, but even at the first run, if the locale is "hu" or "en", the menu just doesn't show. Only the title. I'm testing with 4.1, by the way.

Comment: Are your menus created in XML or in Java?

Comment: They are created in an XML layout.

Comment: The problem is caused by onCreateOptionsMenu, it doesn't get called for some reason..

Comment: That often happens when using fragments - here it is easy to create a new method instead of overriding the existing one due to different signatures for onCreateOptionsMenu between Fragments and Activities. However if it works in the default case, then that may not be your problem.

Comment: This app doesn't even use fragments. The default method is overriden inside the app, and the menu even works in some countries, but it doesn't in others.